Checking MixedModel convergence in Julia
I'm trying to teach myself how to use Julia as an alternative to R, and was running into some trouble with checking convergence of a MixedModel object. In R, if I use the following code
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

lmer( y ~ x1 * x2 + (1 | rand1) + (1 | rand2), df)

and the model doesn't converge, the lmerTest package will warn me. Using the following in julia:
using MixedModels, LinearAlgebra

let model 
    mForm = @formula y ~ x1 * x2 + (1 | rand1) + (1 | rand2)
    fit(MixedModel, mForm, df)
end

I get no warnings, even if the same formula would warn me in R. Is there a similar way to test convergence in julia? There's also a function check_convergence(model) in the 'easystats' package in R, if there's a similar function in some Julia package.
